# Angularjs: Create a new scope property inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The value is never shown on the DOM and i'm just trying to see if this way works..

What i am trying to do is create a new scope value inside the directive and show it to the DOM

```
app.directive("rest", ["restFactory", function($rest){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            uri: "@rest",
        },
        link: function(scope){
            scope.$rest = [];

            $rest.batch(scope.uri)
                .then(function(data){
                    scope.$rest = data;
                });
        }
    }
}]);
```

the data i am trying to show comes from a function that returns a promise, and with the promise comes the data i want to use in the DOM

the HTML is coded like this:

```
<div rest="accounts">
    <div ng-repeat="data in $rest">
        {{data.id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the first directive i ever did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UvlpzCaqP5CZxl3Y8awd) to explain why your directive doesn't work.

```
<div rest="accounts">
    <!-- You can't access the directive variable $rest from here 
         The directives variables are only available on it's template. -->
    <div ng-repeat="data in $rest">
        {{data.id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This will work:

```
app.directive("restTwo", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {},
        // It will work. I put the template in here.
        // You can only access the directive variables from it's template
        template: '<div ng-repeat="data in $rest">{{data.id}}</div>',

        link: function(scope, el, attr) {
            console.log(attr.rest); // output = accounts

            //data
            scope.$rest = [{
                'id': 1,
                'name': 'John Doe'
            }, {
                'id': 2,
                'name': 'Johana Doe'
            }];
            console.log(scope.$rest);
        }
    }
});
```

I suggest you to make a factory and make your api call's in it like this:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function($http) {

    // GET example
    this.get = function(string) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=' + string
        });
    }

    // Your request here
    this.yourRequest = function(uri) {
        // return $rest.batch(uri);
    }

    return this;
});
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myFactory) {
    $scope.myData = [];


    myFactory.get('tetris').then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        $scope.myData = response.data.items;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });

});
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData">
    {{data.id}}
</div>
```

If you **REALLY** want to use a directive for this (I do not recommend): 
Directive:

```
app.directive("restThree", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            'data': '='
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attr) {
            //console.log(attr.rest); // output = accounts

            //data
            scope.$rest = [{
                'id': 1,
                'name': 'John Doe'
            }, {
                'id': 2,
                'name': 'Johana Doe'
            }];

            scope.data = scope.$rest;
        }
    }
});
```

View:

```
<div rest-three="accounts" data="directiveData">
    <div ng-repeat="data in directiveData">
        {{data.id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i will keep all of this in mind

Comment: @nosthertus I forgot to save the last version of the plunker. Now it's updatated